# Unable to get json from instagram: PHP failed to open stream: HTTP request failed

Tags: php, json, instagram-api

I'm trying to develop and Instagram application but I'm struggling to get a json inserting the access token via variable.

That's my code:

```
$personal = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/?access_token={$accesstoken}'));
```

And the error that I receive is this:

```
PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/?access_token={$accesstoken}): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
```

I already tried to see if I get the variable $accesstoken from the previous form and it's all right, because if I echo-it on the page it pops up.
I tried the function preg_replace to understand if the problem were the white spaces, but nothing.
I don't want to use cURL if it is not mandatory.

What's wrong with the code (and me)?

Thanks in advance!

Edit:
As I answered to @FirstOne: yes, I already tried to put the variable (access token) manually and in this way it works.

Comment: What happens if you manually replace the variable in the url and paste it in the browser itself?

Comment: if i am not wrong ,lately instagram changed its API ,and it doesnt let most applications or developers works on it.specially instabots having problem too,therefore json plugins might face problem too!

Comment: @FirstOne if I manually replace the access token, it works, I already tried it but I forgot to mention it, sorry!

Comment: @moh89 so how should I work on it? I don't know how to develop this thing other than using json.